# Using fixtures without a corresponding model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, yaml, fixtures

I currently have some large strings that I would like use as test data when testing a log scraper. It would work well to have these strings in a YAML file.

I would love to refer to them while testing in a short and concise manner such as:

```
log_lines(:incorrect_string)
```

Is there anyway to do this using fixtures, or are they exclusively for use with a corresponding model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your yaml looks like this:

```
:incorrect_string: blah
```

then you can just

```
logs = YAML::load_file('filename')
p logs[:incorrect_string]
```

cheer!